# 1.9 - Incorrect Configurable Product Price

Tags: configurable-product, price, ce-1.9.0.1, associate-products

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.0.1 and having an issue on a Configurable Product for a Jewellery store - refer image below.

I've set the price for the actual configurable product as the lowest price option of the associated products ($2400). I've then set the fixed price for each associated product for the Super product attribute. However, on the front-end, the price shows as $2400, but then when I *Choose an Option* from the attribute drop-down, it adds the price of the associated product option to the price of the configurable product, which then ends up being $4800 or $4873!

I then then tried setting the actual configurable product price to $0, but then this shows the product price as $0 in the catalog view and product detail page.

I've come across [Simple Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html) extension, but this is only compatible up to CE 1.5.

Can anyone please help me out with this confusing dilemma?

**EDIT:** I am using the [Dresscode theme from Themeforest](http://themeforest.net/item/dresscode-responsive-magento-theme/3296245).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of configurable product pricing.

If you don't want to install an extension you need to set the configurable product to the price of the base item (75cm @ $2400) and the price of the 85cm option to $73 fixed, which will make it always more $73 more expensive than the 75cm one (and will display (+$73) in the option dropdown with the default theme.

Assuming the simple products are not in the catalog or searchable, the price you set for them is irrelevant.

As Reinsch has said, there are extensions around that will try and work in an easier to use format.

Comment: Thanks! Don't why I didn't think of that. Let me do this instead and try it out

Comment: Richard, quick question...have you used this approach with any sites you have done? Do you experience any pricing *abnormalities* at any stage (cart, checkout, wishlist, special price, etc)?

Comment: No, on our sites we don't usually have to worry about price differentiating configurable products. The default way is a pain though. The main case that annoys us is if someone puts an order on through the admin section. If the use the sku of the simple product, they'll put it straight in, at it's own price, rather than the price of the configurable option.

Comment: @Richard Can i get help regard configurable product price issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/291238/57334

Answer (score 0):

simple configurable products also works with 1.9.0.1. You should get it on [github](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple) and apply all patches.

Of course there are also some other paid extensions.

Comment: Thanks Reinsch! I actually just found this article which talks about it: http://www.rocketmill.co.uk/wrong-price-being-added-to-cart-by-magento-scp-extension. What are the "patches" you refer to?

Comment: I dont know exactly how i installed it.
I think you have to get this version first:

https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/blob/master/releasedVersions/OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts-0.8.0.tgz


Then install the extra packages:
OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts-0.8.2.MCMv1.tgz
OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts-0.8.2.MCMv2.tgz

I dont know if this is necessary, but if you do it in this order, all of the latest files will be kept.

Then get copy the configurable.php in the "app" folder to your app folder. This should solve the index-problem