# Magento 1.9 - How to debug - Configurable product price changed to 0 if chooses colors attribute

Tags: configurable-product, price, configurable-swatches, magento1.9.2.3, configurable-product-options

I have configurable product if choose different color in products page price return 0,

configuration :

[image]

In my configurable productpage,

[image]

Note :  I am using this extension, https://pluginarchive.com/magento/rp_display_price_free  if i disabled configurable product working fine. How to debug without delete the extension.

How to solve the issue. Any help.

Comment: Which one either Red or Navy blue or both? What is its URL?

Comment: @Agilox my configurable product price 75, red also 75 so that red color price empty (see screen shot above) and navy blue 95 so that add 20, in configurable product page if i choose navy blue price return 0, not calculate 75 + 20 = 95, same if i choose red return price 0

Comment: have you done reindexing?

Comment: yes, i did.......

Comment: @zus: Price and special price changed by javascript Product.OptionsPrice (declared in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml)
  Implementation of the class is in javascript file js/varien/products.js

The function that should change the price is Product.OptionsPrice.reload

That JS object expects your price and special price html elements

Did you try below extension: which will perfect work for configurable product.
https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/#readme

Comment: In localhost working good, live only getting error, may I know possible of errors @sangeetha

Comment: @zus: I believe, you set your configurable product(parent) price as $0(or not set) and hence you are getting this result.
It is better to set the base price for configurable product based on the simple product which cultivates configurable product and the difference in price (for simple products) in the super attribute section.

Comment: @sangeeta As you know if i chooses color : red configurable products price changed to 0, but if i add add-to-cart price looking correct. https://snipboard.io/sdWuEA.jpg how to solve this error?

Comment: @zus can you share/message live url ?

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad Could you pls share what details you need, i will send you?

Comment: live url for testing

Comment: @SangeetaChandaliya  I am using this extension, https://pluginarchive.com/magento/rp_display_price_free  if i disabled configurable product working fine. How to debug without delete the extension.

Comment: Check for answer here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/300364/74277

Answer (score 4):

The most likely issue is that you are using an extension which is changing how configurable products work or your theme is doing it.

Most extensions regarding configurable products change the functionality to use prices directly from the child products (the products assigned to the configurable product).

I can recommend several things you could try that might help you debug this issue:

1. Check if you have any javascript errors on the product view page
2. Check what price you put for the configurable product, if it was
   created programatically, it might have a `null` price which could
   cause problems
3. Check if the configurable product is `in stock`
4. Check if the child products all have a non-zero regular price and
   that they don't have a special price set to 0
5. Make sure the child products are all `in stock` and that they have `quantity > 0`
6. Try putting a 0 in the red color option instead of just a blank
7. If you have an extension that is affecting configurable products,
   you can try switching it off
8. Try switching to the default Magento theme and check if it's working
   then

Comment: FYI if I try with default theme it's working, let me try with your other steps.

Comment: As you know if i chooses color : red configurable products price changed to 0, but if i add add-to-cart price looking correct. https://snipboard.io/sdWuEA.jpg how to solve this error? @Lez

Comment: Did you try my other suggestions? The problem might also be that you made some changes to `/catalog/product/view.phtml` or `/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml`? For example, if you had changed some classes of the price element or some of it's parents, the theme functionality to change the configurable product price might have broke. Also, what happens if you change the color to navy blue? Do you get 95 Rs?

Comment: Yes, i did some changes in app/design/frontend/default/theme327k/template/catalog/product/view.phtml. How can i change my view.phtml with better way, i want my configurable product should be work? @Lez

Comment: There is nothing I can say without seeing the contents of the `view.phtml` and comparing the original with the modified version. My advice is to put back the original `view.phtml` theme file and check if it works then. If it does, then maybe you can figure out what change has broken the functionality. Maybe it isn't connected to view.phtml, but maybe it's some other part of the theme... I cannot say exactly without looking at the files and/or the shop URL. Good luck to you @zus

Comment: After replaced with fresh view.phtml still getting same error. @Lez

Comment: @zus, did you clear the cache after replace?

Comment: Yes I tried, clear the cache & flush the cache & reindexed. Still I am faced this issue.

Comment: @Lez I am using this extension, https://pluginarchive.com/magento/rp_display_price_free  if i disabled configurable product working fine. How to debug without delete the extension.

Comment: I checked the extension and the error is probably connected with the text "free" which the extension is replacing when price is 0. Most probably, for configurable products there is a functionality which tries to do some numeric calculations. For example 0 + 10 = 10 and with this extension it tries to do "FREE" + 10 = ERROR. If you don't need the "FREE" text for configurable products, then you can adjust the extension funcionality and check if the product is configurable before the extension replaces 0 with "FREE".

Comment: Here's a link where you have an example how to check the product type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331887/get-product-id-and-product-type-in-magento