# Magento 1.9 - How to Debug 3rd party Extension which is affect Magneto Core Function?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, debug

I have installed free price extension, https://pluginarchive.com/magento/rp_display_price_free  the extension collapse my configurable product price. How to debug which part of the extension affects my Magento core function.

Note: https://snipboard.io/I2FrSH.jpg

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: What you want to achieve using this plugin?
Add `var spConfig` and `var optionsPrice` javascript full array into the question from website config detail page.

Comment: check the answer i guess it may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of points would like to add here that one can not easily render string (in this case its **FREE** - system config (`displayfreeprice/general/freeprice_text`) ) into the price format which may be float or decimal in most of the cases.

Although, one workaround should resolve this issue showing **0.00** instead of its value.

You can do as follows:

1. `Open <magento-root>\app\code\local\Rp\Displayfreeprice\Helper\Productprice.php`
2. Look for the function named
   `public static function currency( $price , $format=true , $includeContainer = true )`
3. Find the below statement.

`return parent::formatPrice($price, $includeContainer);`

4. Replace it with below statement.

   `return parent::currency($price, $includeContainer);`

Refresh the cache and session and then open configurable product page.

I guess extension vendor FORGOT to replace the function name.

Comment: May i know how did you find the error? @MageSoftech

Comment: Looked at their overwritten file and compared with the core file...Enjoy coding.

Comment: Okay, find overwritten by using Padhiyar Gaurang script then do correction. Thanks for let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't work with Magento 1 for a long time. It's just my suggestion: We should have Debug tools.

- PHP: Xdebug and PHPStorm are perfect choices. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html
- Javascript: Developer Tool https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Price calculation flow is not easy.

Read more:

[Magento 1.9 - How to debug - Configurable product price changed to 0 if chooses colors attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291238/magento-1-9-how-to-debug-configurable-product-price-changed-to-0-if-chooses)

Will update more here.

Comment: Is possible configure xdebug in PHP ver 5.6

Comment: Sure. You can do that.

Answer (score 1):

create file at root of magento with name **rewritelist.php** and run

```
<?php
$foldersToCheck = array('app/code/local/', 'app/code/community/');
$configFiles = array();
foreach ($foldersToCheck as $folder){
    $files = glob($folder.'*/*/etc/config.xml');//get all config.xml files in the specified folder
    $configFiles = array_merge($configFiles, $files);//merge with the rest of the config files
}
$rewrites = array();//list of all rewrites

foreach ($configFiles as $file){
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadXML(file_get_contents($file));
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $path = '//rewrite/*';//search for tags named 'rewrite'
        $text = $xpath->query($path);
        foreach ($text as $rewriteElement){
            $type = $rewriteElement->parentNode->parentNode->parentNode->tagName;//what is overwritten (model, block, helper)
            $parent = $rewriteElement->parentNode->parentNode->tagName;//module identifier that is being rewritten (core, catalog, sales, ...)
            $name = $rewriteElement->tagName;//element that is rewritten (layout, product, category, order)
            foreach ($rewriteElement->childNodes as $element){
                $rewrites[$type][$parent.'/'.$name][] = $element->textContent;//class that rewrites it
            }
        }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($rewrites);
```

Comment: this is what i get -> https://snipboard.io/hsWG1t.jpg

Comment: what i need to do further?

Comment: which core functionality is modified?

Comment: please upvote if it helps you to get rewrited files list.

Comment: Configurable products price mismatch.

Comment: If I choose color or size of the configurable products price return 0.

Comment: Helper Rp_Displayfreeprice_Helper_ProductPrice override core/data helper.
Check here it might possible here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102875/discussion-between-padhiyar-gaurang-and-zus).